# How do you point the current branch at the working directory in Bazaar VCS?

Tags: pointers, version-control, bazaar, working-directory

I am trying to set up Bazaar for our sites but am having trouble achieving the exact setup I want.  Basically, I want one folder that contains all the information for each site, such as:

```
/var/www/site1
/var/www/site2
/var/www/site3
...
```

I would like to set up the trunk and any branches for each site within these folders. I would like the folder itself to point to act as a working directory, such that whatever branch I happen to be on is mirrored in the site folder, such that our server can get to it.

Any ideas on how to go about this?